# How to get correct lightning in the shadows?

Tags: lighting, shadows

I just started learning Blender. After I finished my first scene I saw some problems in the shadows. Is there someone who can help me out and tell what I could improve to get rid of these problems?

My lighting setup is one area light from the left (blue arrow A) and one point light from the right (blue arrow B). In both lights I check marked shadows with bias at 0 and clip start at 0.05.

**Red area**: The shadow seems to be rather further down the edge then right in the edge. Also the lighting is not very even.
**Yellow area**: There is no proper shadow around the legs, maybe the legs are even emitting some light.

Hopefully someone can help me out :)
Cheers, Julian

[image: Shadow problems]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got I myself. Didn't changed my render engine from Eevee to Cycles..

So much better :)

[image]